# WCF сервис обрабатывает входящие запросы в одном потоке, не смотря на ConcurrencyMode.Multiple

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Простейший WCF сервис в консольном приложении и такой же клиент. Клиент одновременно (в разных потоках) отправляет на сервер N запросов. Ожидается, что сервер для обработки поступившей одновременно кучи запросов так же выделит несколько потоков и после секундного простоя (специально сделан Thread.Sleep(1000)) примерно одновременно вернет ответы клиенту, но этого не происходит. Сервис обрабатывает все запросы в одном потоке (это видно по ThreadId на скриншоте), несмотря на то, что в атрибуте ServiceBehavior выставлено значение ConcurrencyMode.Multiple.

Код сервера:

```
namespace Server
{
  using System;
  using System.ServiceModel;
  using System.Threading;

  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IServer
  {
    [OperationContract]
    int GetResult(int value);
  }

  [ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,  
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
  public class Server: IServer
  {
    public int GetResult(int value)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("In: {0}, Time: {1}, ThreadId: {2}", 
                        value, DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

      Thread.Sleep(1000);

      Console.WriteLine("                                                   Out: {0}, Time: {1}, ThreadId: {2}",
                        value, DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
      return value;
    }
  }


  class Program
  {
    static void Main()
    {
      var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Server));
      host.Open();

      Console.WriteLine("Service started");

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Код клиента:

```
using System;

namespace Server
{
  using System.ServiceModel;

  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IServer
  {
    [OperationContract]
    int GetResult(int value);
  }
}

namespace Client
{
  using System.ServiceModel;
  using System.Threading;

  using Server;

  class Program
  {
    static object lockObj = new object();

    static void Main()
    {
      ChannelFactory<IServer> factory = new ChannelFactory<IServer>("defaultEndPoint");
      IServer channel = factory.CreateChannel();


      const int threadCount = 20;
      int value = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
      {
        new Thread(state =>
          {
            int n;
            lock (lockObj)
            {
              value++;
              n = value;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Send value = {0}, Time = {1}", n, DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
            n = channel.GetResult(n);
            Console.WriteLine("                                          Response value = {0}, Time = {1}", n, DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
          }).Start();
      }

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Конфиг сервера:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DefaultBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1000" maxConcurrentInstances="1000" maxConcurrentSessions="1000"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="Server.Server" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior">
        <endpoint contract="Server.IServer" binding="basicHttpBinding" address=""/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:7803/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup></configuration>
```

Что происходит на клиенте:

[image: Клиент]

Что происходит на сервере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ларчик открывался просто. Конечно же, нужно было создавать свой канал "IServer channel = factory.CreateChannel();" для каждого потока.